# How to add external dependency to a project in github when u use that external dependency in your project?

Tags: java, github, dependencies

So i recently uploaded my GUI calculator project in GitHub for which i used exp4j
I've dragged the project file and uploaded it in repository without uploading external dependency.

**Would my code run in other user's device if they download project files?**

Comment: How were you managing your dependencies? Did you use maven/gradle or just added the jar files in your classpath?